# Immediate Timer job wont start

Tags: timer-jobs

I have an immediate timer job that stopped working on the 7th July.
It is the only timer job that has stopped and will not run.

I've restarted the services, set the job to run every 1 min, reset IIS. 
Even rebooted the app server.

Am I missing something simple?
Should I delete and recreate the job, if so are there any pitfalls I should be wary of?

Thanks

Comment: just to clarify, what do you mean by 'immediate' timer job? Normally I would associate that term with a one-off, or one-time job, but it seems you have yours set up as a 'scheduled' job.

Comment: @profilesfrankodlive: Please only use the community wiki option when asking 'discussion style' questions. Otherwise no-one is able to gain reputation on your post. See http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/432/what-does-community-wiki-mean for more info. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Delete the timer job definition and start again.  It may have a stale "running job" recorded in the Config database.  If this is true, it will still show the job as running even when it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the ULS log for errors related to the timer job?

Comment: I didn't, poor show on my part.
Event ID:5uuf
Log: The previous instance of the timer job 'Application Server Administration Service Timer Job', id '{35C862E7-5A24-4E8B-B463-842460B8824D}' for service '{422146C8-6289-4FC9-A3A1-0438B111DF5D}' is still running, so the current instance will be skipped.  Consider increasing the interval between jobs.

The interval has been tried at 1, 15, 30 & 55 minutes. Still will not run.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I didn't, poor show on my part.

Event ID:5uuf

Log: The previous instance of the timer job 'Application Server Administration Service Timer Job', id '{35C862E7-5A24-4E8B-B463-842460B8824D}' for service '{422146C8-6289-4FC9-A3A1-0438B111DF5D}' is still running, so the current instance will be skipped. Consider increasing the interval between jobs.

The interval has been tried at 1, 15, 30 & 55 minutes. Still will not run.

The job id that I want to run is not the job id in the logs. I have noticed that the timer job was aborted at 02:20.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you restart the "Windows SharePoint Services Timer" service after reinstalling/reactivating your feature. If you're trying all of these intervals and none of them are working there's a good chance you haven't done this and your job is still attempting to run old code. If your job is set to run across multiple web front ends, you must also reset this service on the other web front ends.

Also, note that your timer job will wait until that interval to run the first time. If you create a job on an interval of 5 minutes and you activate it at 12:00 it won't run until 12:05. If you're running an immediate job and it's not firing, have you tried the execadmsvcjobs operation of STSADM?